# How to create a metric in a connected locally finite abstract graph?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces, random-graphs

First of all sorry for my English. I want to create a metric in a graph $(V, E)$ where $V$ is the countable set of vertices, $E$ the set of edges. The graph is non-directed, connected, locally finite. The purpose of the metric is to define an isometry where the edges are isometric to $[0,1]$ or to $\mathbb{S}^1$. My first idea was define the metric in $V$ (the distance between two vertices would be the minimum length of the paths between them), but I have to give a metric in $E$ because I have to make the edges isometric to some sets. Also, i have to make the edges a set and not a point, can I make the edges some type of segment between the vertices?

Comment: Your idea of the minimum length of the paths seems fine. Maybe you can write it down formally, then it is easier to verify. Cleary you can "interpolate" between vertices as you want, just pick your favourite metric.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you might find this article useful: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.07549v2.pdf